# Data Structure Creation (PQ linked list merge?)

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, priority-queue

So I need to find a data structure for this situation that I'll describe:
This is not my problem but explains the data structure aspect i need more succinctly:
I have an army made up of platoons. Every platoon has a number of men and a rank number(highest being better). If an enemy were to attack my army, they would kill some POWER of my army, starting from the weakest platoon and working up, where it takes (platoon rank) amount of power to kill every soldier from a platoon.

I could easily simulate enemies attacking me by peeking and popping elements from my priority queue of platoons, ordered by rank number, but that is not what I need to do. What i need is to be able to allow enemies to view all the soldiers they would kill if they attacked me, without actually attacking, so without actually deleting elements from my priorityqueue(if i implemented it as a pq).

Sidenote: Java's PriorityQueue.Iterator() prints elements in a random order, I know an iterator is all I need, just fyi.

The problem is, if I implemented this as a pq, I can only see the top element, so I would have to pop platoons off as if they were dying and then push them back on when the thought of the attack has been calculated. I could also implement this as a linked list or array, but insertion takes too long. Ultimately I would love to use a priority queue I just need the ability to view either the (pick an index)'th element from the pq, or to have every object in the pq have a pointer to the next object in the pq, like a linked list.

Is this thought about maintaining pointers with a pq like a linked list possible within java's PriorityQueue? Is it implemented for me somewhere in PriorityQueue that I dont know about? is the index thing implemented? is there another data structure I can use that can better serve my purpose? Is it realistic for me to find the source code from Java's PriorityQueue and rewrite it on my machine to maintain these pointers like a linked list?
Any ideas are very welcome, not really sure which path I want to take on this one.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is an [augmented binary search tree](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall07/Lectures/augtrees.pdf).  That would allow efficient access to the nth smallest element while still keeping the elements ordered.  You could also use a [threaded binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree).  That would allow you to step from one element to the next larger one in constant time, which is faster than in a normal binary tree.  Both of these data structures are slower than a heap, though.